# Changing an element of Queue without a temporary list, queue or other data structure

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, doubly-linked-list

Doing exercises from the book Java Methods by Litvin. One problem asks to create a LinkedList that implements the Queue interface.

> A Morse code message is represented in a program as a queue of strings.
> Each string consists of dots and dashes.
> Write and test a method
> that replaces each question mark (represented by "..--..") with a period
> (".-.-.-"), leaving all other codes unchanged. Do not use any temporary
> lists, queues, or other data structures.

Since the LinkedList implements a Queue, I am unable to use the ListIterator. I'm unsure as to how to change the values of the elements in the Queue without placing them in a temporary place. How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: What is a "Queue based Linked List of Strings"?  Please say exactly what you mean.  Are these the Java SE classes `Queue` and `LinkedList`?  If they are, what do you mean by `Queue` **based**?

Comment: (We are not going to help you if you don't explain the problem you are trying to solve clearly enough that we can understand it.)

Comment: It sounds as though each item in the queue contains the complete morse code representation of a character "Each string consists of dots and dashes" so isn't this rather easy, compared to the case where each string was a single dot, dash or pause.

Comment: @Stephen C When I said Queue based Linked List, I meant a LinkedList implementing the Queue interface.

Comment: 1)  What about the other questions that I asked? 2) Update the question.  Use the EDIT button ....

Comment: But assuming that you are talking about a Java SE `java.util.LinkedList`, the solution involves using the `LinkedList.listIterator()` method.  Look at the javadoc for `ListIterator`.

Comment: @tgdavies yes each string contains the dots and dashes that represent a word. Is it possible to change the values?

Comment: I've updated my question. @StephenC I've tried to use the ListIterator but since the LinkedList implements the Queue interface I get the error "symbol:   method listIterator()
  location: variable morseCode of type Queue<String>"

Comment: You need to cast it to a `LinkedList` so that you can use the `LinkedList` specific methods on the queue object.

Comment: A class inheriting from `LinkedList` is still a `LinkedList` even if it additionally implements the `Queue` interface. So of course, you can still use the iterator like for any other `LinkedList` But it's hard to help you, if you don't show any code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question could use some code to show your current state of work.
But without further information:

1. A queue only grants you access to the first element by design of FIFO.
2. You can always remove the first element and insert it at the back.
3. If you do that for all elements in the queue without changing each element, the queue ends up in the same state as before.

Hence, this would be a possible solution with only using the Queue interface:

```
public void replaceQuestionmarks(Queue<String> input) {
  for(int i = 0; i<input.size(); input++) {
    String current = input.remove();
    input.add(questionMarkToPeriod(current));
}
```

"questionMarkToPeriod" would be a method for the conditional replacement.

Edit: Forgot the generic type in Queue.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what the book was trying to get me to do. Will definitely to be more clear with questions in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted then. It is my first one :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @StephenC and @tgdavies I figured out the problem. After casting the LinkedList, I was able to use the ListIterator and update the values from there

```
public static void replace(Queue<String> morseCode)
    {
        ListIterator<String> iter = ((LinkedList<String>)(morseCode)).listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            if(iter.next() == "..--..")
            {
                iter.set(".-.-.-");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Will try to make my questions more understandable in the future.